# Can't install ptqt5-tools package

Tags: python, pyqt5

When I want to download pyqt5-tools package, I get en error like

[image: first installment]

And the rest says like

[image: actual error]

What can I do to be able to download the package itself?

Comment: PyQt tools doesn't support Python 3.10 yet. Downgrade to python 3.9. Also, for future reference, always add output/debug as text, not images.

Comment: @musicamante, thanks for your reply. I deleted version 3.10 and downloaded 3.9. It works perfectly fine now. Again, thank you for your answer.